# Crispy forms layout different in local server and Ubuntu server

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-crispy-forms

I am using crispy forms in my django forms and formset. It Worked as expected in the local server when run the same project in Ubuntu server its layout is different. For example, I am created a two column form using following code:

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Person
    exclude =('user',)


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MemberForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Your full name. 100 characters.'
    self.fields['tele_land'].label = 'Land phone'
    self.fields['tele_cell'].label = 'Cell phone'
    self.fields['passing_year'].label = 'Passing year'
    self.fields['passing_year'].help_text = 'According to your session year'

    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
    self.helper.form_tag = False
    self.helper.layout = Layout(

        Div(
            Div('name', 'name_in_bangla', 'nick_name', 'birth_date','blood_group','present_address','permanent_address','tele_land','tele_cell','photo','admission_session','degree_obtained','passing_year', 'category','is_active',css_class='col-md-5'),
            Div(css_class='col-xs-2'),
            Div('payment_number','bank_name','branch_name','profession', 'Designation', 'organization', 'official_address','office_phone', 'office_mobile','office_email','office_fax',' website','father_name','mother_name','is_married','national_id_no','passport_no','spouse_name','spouse_blood_group', css_class='col-md-5'), css_class='row-crispy'
        ),
```

In localhost:8000 it gives two columns form but in Ubuntu server it gives one column form which is not desired. In another form it didn't show slug field which is shown by the localhost.

Does anyone suggest me what will get rid of this behavior.

Comment: this should have nothing to do with the OS in general but with module versions used there - how do you install you python dependencies?

Comment: After sometime of reboot my Ubuntu server, it worked as expected.